# SignalR hub and Identity.Claims

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm using SignalR for sending notifications from server (Asp.net MVC) to client, and in my OnConnected() method I've register users with login name (email):

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
Groups.Add(connectionId, userName);
return base.OnConnected();
}
```

Now I want to use accountId instead of name, and I trying that with Identity.Claims. Inside my Login method in controller I've created new ClaimsIdentity

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
----

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Email), }, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "guest"));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "A Person"));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, validation.AccountId.ToString())); //from db

AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
{ IsPersistent = true}, identity);

AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);

-----
}

private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{
get
{
return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
}
}
```

I can't access my ClaimsIdentity inside my OnConnected method in Hub, using this:

```
var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)Context.User.Identity).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

and using similar ways. I try many different ways but I've always have felling that mvc controller and signalr hub don't use same HttpContext, or something override my claims. I also try to set new identity like this:

```
    IPrincipal principal = 
new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("myuser"), new string[] { "myrole" });
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```

or

```
HttpContext.User = principal;
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the claim from `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` instead of the `HubCallerContext` which SignalR exposes?

Answer (score 6):

Check out this-

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)Context.User.Identity;
var tmp= identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Make sure you call Authentication before SignalR in your startup class.

```
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<MainHub>("/hubs/main");
        });
```